# iOS tableview is null after coming to foreground

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata, foreground

I see that the tableview is null after coming to foreground though I have made referencing outlet and outlet connections to the class. Since tableview is null, relsoaddata is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: show something, you showed nothing !!

Comment: provide us some code.

Comment: -(void)Reloaddata{
    NSLog(@"tableView is '%@'",tableView);
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  Once I come to the foreground I preform, - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData];  NSLog(@"reloading");});

//    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}  and then I receive update from the server about the tableview list update, update the username array and then call Reloaddata.

Comment: how is your tableView property declared ? You should add this code in your post in code tags so that it's readable.

Comment: @Champoul- tableView property is declared as follows:  {@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;}